# you can't use `macro parameter character #` in horizontal line

Tags: verbatim

I have the following latex code that I tried to decorate a fragment of html code:

```
[``temperatures'', ``root'', ``\verb#*<TABLE*<TABLE*</TR>#</TABLE>*#'']
```

but I got error message said:

```
You can't use `macro parameter character #` in horizontal line
```

I am wondering how to fix this issue.

thanks

Comment: Well, you have *three* occurrences of `#` in your `\verb` call.  `#` is a special character, so when it hits the first, it's turned into the delimiter.  When it hits the second, verb content is over and `#` regains its special meaning.  When it hits the third, `:(`  Change the delimiting characters to something like `|` or `@` (or really *any* character that isn't in the content).  Possible dupe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **54.3 Verbatim**; emphasis added):

> The command `\verb` produces in-line verbatim text, where the argument is
>   delimited by *any* pair of characters.

So, since you're probably interested in using `#` as part of the verbatim text, use a different delimiter pair, since `#` is not allowed as the error message says:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
[``temperatures'', ``root'', ``\verb!*<TABLE*<TABLE*</TR>#</TABLE>*!'']
\end{document}
```

Why did the error message occur? The first matched pair in

```
\verb#*<TABLE*<TABLE*</TR>#</TABLE>*#
```

is actually

```
\verb#*<TABLE*<TABLE*</TR>#
```

leaving

```
</TABLE>*#
```

with a dangling `#`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have *three* occurrences of `#` in your `\verb` call.  `#` is a special character, so when it hits the first, it's turned into the delimiter.  When it hits the second, verb content is over and `#` regains its special meaning.  When it hits the third, `:(`  Change the delimiting characters to something like `|` or `@` (or really *any* character that isn't in the content).

Something like

```
[``temperatures'', ``root'', ``\verb+*<TABLE*<TABLE*</TR>#</TABLE>*+'']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a `#` character in your file but still having the same error message, than do the following:

```
1) delete the .aux and the .bbl files in your folder
2) Recompile
```

This is the only thing that worked to me.

*Hope it helps !*